# Two Quadratics, the roots of one are the coefficients of the other and vice versa.... can they exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

I spent hours on this... feel pretty pathetic.  I read this on an old AMATYC exam:

Let $\quad c, \quad$ and $\quad d\quad$ be the roots of $\quad x^2+ax+b$

and let $\quad a, \quad$ and $\quad b\quad$ be the roots of $\quad x^2+cx+d$

What is the value of $$a+b+c+d$$
Somehow, I am to reason that this value is $\quad -2$

I do realize that this must mean that
$$\begin{cases}
a&=-(c+d) \\
b&=cd \\
c&=-(a+b) \\
d&=ab \\
\end{cases}$$
would have a solution, but **I cannot show one exists, can you find an example?**...

the first and third equations alone imply that you can set two of the four variables free:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1 \\ 1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=0 \quad \sim \quad\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=0$$
so that
$$\begin{cases}
a&=-c-d \\
b&=d \\
c&=c \\
d&=d\\
\end{cases}$$

perhaps new letters?... kidding but:

$$x^2-(r_1+r_2)x+r_1r_2 \qquad \text{vs}\qquad x^2+(r_1+r_2-r_1r_2)x-r_1r_2(r_1+r_2)$$

works only one way: the roots of second are the coefficients of the first alright, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picking up where the OP left off.

> $$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
> a&=-(c+d) \quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{1}\\
> b&=cd \quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{2} \\
> c&=-(a+b) \quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{3}\\
> d&=ab \quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{4}\\
> \end{align}\end{cases}$$

Subtracting $\,(1)-(3)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\cancel{a} - \bcancel{c} = -(\bcancel{c}+d) + (\cancel{a}+b) \quad\iff\quad b = d
$$

Using $\,b = d\,$ in $\,(2)\,$, $\,(4)\,$:

$$
b = cb \quad\iff\quad
b = 0 \;\;\lor\;\; c = 1
\\ b = ab \quad\iff\quad
b = 0 \;\;\lor\;\; a = 1
$$

- $b = d = 0 \implies c = -a\,$ from $(1)$ and therefore $a+b+c+d = 0\,$.
- $b = d \ne 0 \implies a = c = 1 \implies a + b + c + d = -(a+c) = -2$ from $\,(1) + (3)\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ For a brute force approach using heavier machinery, let $\,t=a+b+c+d\,$ be the sum in question. Eliminating $a,b,c,d$ between $(1)-(4)$ and the expression for $t$ results (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Ba+%2B+b+%2B+c%2C+a+%2B+c+%2B+d%2C+b+-+c+d%2C+a+b+-+d%2C+t+-+a+-+b+-+c+-+d%7D%2C+%7Bt%7D%2C+%7Ba%2C+b%2C+c%2C+d%7D%5D)) in the equation $\,t(t+2)= 0\,$ with roots $0, -2$.

Comment: Thank you for using what I had already done.... and then showing where I failed to go.... and justifying your steps as well!

Comment: @SideProj314 Glad it helped. You had it framed right, it just needed finishing off.

Answer (score 4):

$a+c+d = a+b+c = 0$ implies $b=d=-(a+c)$. If $b=d\neq 0$, then $a=c=1$ and $a+b+c+d = -2$. However, if $b=d=0$, then $c=-a$ works and $a+b+c+d = 0$.

The pairs of equations are $(x^2+x-2=0, x^2+x-2=0)$ with roots $1$ and $-2$, and $(x^2+ ax+ 0=0, x^2-ax+0=0)$: the first has roots $-a$ and 0, and the second has roots $a$ and 0.

Comment: Thank you...Can you show an example of two quadratics with this property?

Comment: Thank you... but those parabolas are the same... the second example is a triviality with $b=d=0$ can there be a non-trivial example or do they **have** to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

So $a^2+ca+d=0$ and substituting $a=-(c+d)$ we get $(c+d)^2-c(c+d)+d=0 \implies d(c+d+1)=0 \implies c+d=-1$. 
Note that if $d=0$ we have that $a^2+ca=0 \implies c=a=b=d=0$. Similarly, $a+b=-1$

Comment: Thank you Vasli.  I see why $a+b+c+d=-2$, can you show me an example of two quadratics with this property?

Comment: @SideProj314: this implies that $a=c=1, b=d=-2$ because $a=-(c+d)$ and $c=-(a+b)$

Comment: so ... the requirements pin us down to exactly two ways for this to be true... but in both ways they have to be the same quadratic.... bit of a let down but ok thank you....